# Joomla 3.2 site Admin panel is not working

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 3.2 site. My site's admin panel was working fine before sometime. But now it's showing blank page when i am accessing administrator account using valid admin url.

When i inspected it with firebug i found that it's not getting some files. Then i checked my cpanel but all files were present at correct location. I have also given all permission(777) to folder.

My site's front end is working fine but admin panel is not working.
my site's url : http://joomla3.guru99.com

Here's snapshots of my issue : http://screencast.com/t/8TNc6yqemKl

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the site in any way? Have you by any chance renamed the admin folder? Have you installed any plugins recently? Has the site been moved to a new host? Before doing anything, change the folders back to 755 for security reasons and also due to the fact that Joomla doesn't like 777

Comment: i have not made any changes to site, not renamed folder, not installed any plugins, not moved my site to another host. but still I'm getting this error.

Comment: Was this a site that was updated or one that was fresh installed as 3.2? If it was updated make sure that all the files that were supposed to be deleted were actually deleted.  If you have command line access you can run the cli script for this that you can find in  the cli folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your administration page, view its source, you will see this:

```
  <style type="text/css">
html { display:none }
  </style>
```

You just need to remove it.

Comment: but why i'm getting 404 files not found error ?

Comment: @Hung Tran - This solves the blank page issue however the scripts are not being imported correctly still

Comment: Hmm, Why don't you disable SH404SEF first. I get this in your front-end: You asked for {%sh404SEF_404_URL%}, but despite our computers looking very hard, we could not find it. What happened.     {sh404sefSimilarUrlsCommentStart}It's not the end of everything though : you may be interested in the following pages on our site:{sh404sefSimilarUrlsCommentEnd} {sh404sefSimilarUrls}

Comment: We have disabled sh404SEF plugin but problem is same. http://joomla3.guru99.com/administrator/. do you think is it the issue of template or any other third party plugin???

Comment: I thought that SH404SEF could be the reason, that is why I asked you to disabled it. But now we can see that it is not. It seems all the data in your media folder can not be accessed. You said you have set 777 permission to the folder, how about the subfolders and files inside the folder? Did you change the permission recursively (apply to all subfolders and files) or only change for the media folder only?